# Find the c constant in the probability distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability distribution function is given as:
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\frac c{x_1x_2^3}, \ \ if \ \ 1<x_1<x_2$$
$$f(x_1,x_2)=0, \ \ elsewhere$$

I need to find the **c** constant, therefore I know the double integral needs to be equal to 1. I don't know how to determine the boundaries of such definite integrals. Is this one correct? Because it doesn't remove the x2 and therefore I cannot determine the **c**:
$$\int_1^{x_2}(\int_{x_1}^{\infty}\frac c{x_1x_2^3}dx_2)dx_1$$
In this case, x1 has values from 1 to x2 and x2 has values from x1 to infinity, however the calculation of the integral doesn't provide me with satisfying results.

Comment: $x_1$ runs from $1$ to $\infty$.   Given $x_1$,  $x_2$ runs from $x_1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Please show your calculation of the integral.

Comment: The upper bound for the outer integral should be $\infty$, not $x_2$. From there the iterated integral is a straightforward computation.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. You can use $\text{...}$ to include text in equations, and $\mathit{...}$ to include italic text in equations. As you can see, using the formatting for variables to simulate text results in incorrect spacing.